# Change weight threshold in bnlearn package

Tags: r

I am using the `bnlearn` package in r, which generates Bayesian networks using data. I am trying to get more connections between the data nodes, and hence, I am trying to decrease the weight threshold necessary to generate arcs between the nodes. I am using the `gs` function in the bnlearn package, which uses a grow-shrink algorithm. So far, I have tried modifying the alpha threshold, but that appears to change the threshold of error.

Ultimately, my goal is to have the algorithm create more arcs between the points.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to first find the weight of all arcs, and selectively filter them yourself. I don't think bnlearn has that built in.